# Can you use generating functions to solve recurrence relations where the recurrence relation also depends on *subsequent* values?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I'm aware of how to use generating functions to solve recurrence relations of the form $a_n = f(a_{n-1}, \dots, a_{n-k})$ but what if $a_n$ depends on subsequent values?

Consider: $a_0 = 1$ and $a_i = \frac{2}{3}a_{i+1} + \frac{1}{3}a_{i-1}$ for $a > 0$.

(In probabilistic terms, if we have a random walk where up prob is 2/3 and down is 1/3, then $p_i$ is the probability of eventually hitting $0$ when we start at $i$)

Then let $a(x) = \sum_{i \geq 0} a_ix^i $ be the generating function.

Note that:

$a(x) = \sum_{i \geq 0} a_ix^i = \sum_{i\geq 1} (\frac{2}{3}a_{i+1} + \frac{1}{3}a_{i-1})x^i + 1 = \frac{2}{3} \sum_{i \geq 1}a_{i+1}x^i + \frac{1}{3} \sum_{i \geq 1}a_{i-1}x^i + 1  =\frac{2}{3x} \sum_{i \geq 2} a_{i}x^i + \frac{x}{3}\sum_{i \geq 0} a_ix^i$

$ = \frac{2}{3x}\big(a(x) - a_2x - 1  \big) + \frac{x}{3} a(x) + 1$

At this point you're left with an $a_2$ there which cannot be solved for.

Am I making a mistake here or do I need a different approach?

Comment: In general, for a second-order recurrence like this, you will need two initial conditions to specify it uniquely.  And, yes, such recurrence may be solved using generating functions.

Comment: You just rearrange the recurrence; solve for $a_{i+1}$ in terms of the others.